# Problems when trying to attach to a process using jdb

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I need to attach a jdb debug session to a java application that is being executed in a remote host, but I am unable to do it. I am working on linux, with openjdk 1.8.0_65, 64-Bit Server VM.

## What I have tried

In order to enable the port listening, I have run the java application adding the following arguments to the command line:

```
-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

The following message is displayed in the console:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

And the application starts running normally.

Then, from the remote host, I execute the following command:

```
> jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=<remote_host>,port=8000
```

It fails, the output is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
[...]
Fatal error:
Unable to attach to target VM.
```

## What I have checked

In order to check that the port is actually open and I can connect to it from the remote host, I have performed the following operations:

Lets call the host that is executing the java app. `hostA`, and the one from which I wan to attach the `jdb` `hostB`, then:

**Check that there is actually a socket listening on port 8000 in hostA**

```
> netstat -tualpn  | grep :8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1399/<app_name>
```

**In hostA, check that I can connect to the port 8000 (in other words, try to connect from the local host)**

```
> nc -vz localhost 8000
nc: connect to localhost port 8000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost 8000 port [tcp/irdmi] succeeded!
```

With `telnet`, it seems that it can connect but the connection is closed as soon as it is stablished, maybe because the JVM is expecting some sort of request?

```
> telnet localhost 8000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The java app. displays the following message when telnet connection is closed:

```
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshak
```

**From hostB, check that I can connect to hostA, port 8000**

```
> nc -vz hostA 8000
nc: connect to hostA port 8000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

With telnet:

```
> telnet hostA 8000
Trying 172.17.10.127...
telnet: connect to address 172.17.10.127: Connection refused
```

So, I can't connect from `hostA` to `hostB` through the port 8000, although the JVM is listenning in the port 8000, in `hostA`.

**Since the above fails, I have checked if the firewall is causing the connection refused. I have done it by using the nc command:**

In `hostA`:

```
# First kill the java app (otherwise the port is busy), then:
> nc -l 8000
```

In `hostB`:

```
> nc -vz <hostA> 8000
Connection to hostA 8000 port [tcp/irdmi] succeeded!
```

As far as I understand, the above means that there is no firewall (or equivalent) blocking the port.

## EDIT

Of course, I have tried to do `jdb -attach` but it fails even doing it from `hostA`.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it from the same computer?

Comment: Yes, it is the step "In hostA, check that I can connect to the port 8000"

Comment: I see.  I'm not too familiar with the nc command; in hostA, how come `nc -vz localhost 8000` fails and then succeeds?

Comment: I do not know. I have search what is `irdmi`, but I have not found anything usefull for my problem.

Comment: I have added a new checking from both `hostA` and `hostB` with telnet

Comment: I am performing all the above operations connected through ssh to both `hostA` and `hostB`, I assume that this has nothing to do with the `jvm/jdb` connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the connection problem. In the command I use to launch the java application, I have changed the address parameter as following:

Before:

```
-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

After (see `address`):

```
-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough points to comment.  So I'm including this as an answer.  It really isn't.  BUT:

-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8000,serv=y,suspend=n

Isn't it supposed to be:

-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8000,serv**er**=y,suspend=n

??

[EDIT] You are probably already accounting for this - but also, if you are listening on 127.0.0.1, then it stands to reason that you won't connect from a remote computer.  No doubt you are using an actual address, and just didn't include it here...

Comment: Yes, actually I am using **server**, I have copied it wrong. Apologies.